# Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet appearing as unclaimed on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-kernel, broadcom

I'm new to linux & I'm trying to add external ethernet NIC to `hpe dl380 gen9` server, the os is **ubuntu 20.04**.

I can't find the NICs using `ifconfig`, and after some googling I used
`lshw -C network` and it's appearing as `network unclaimed`

full description:

`Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet [14e4:168e] (rev 11)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `linux-firmware` and  `linux-modules`, the kernel driver is `bnx2x.ko`.

```
sudo apt install linux-firmware linux-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo modprobe -v bnx2x
```

In debian is packaged under `firmware-bnx2x`, here is t[he description](https://packages.debian.org/sid/firmware-bnx2x):

> This package contains the binary firmware for Broadcom NetXtreme II 10Gb network adapters supported by the bnx2x driver.

Comment: For Arch based OS (Manjaro) the command to install firmware directly is `sudo pacman -S linux-firmware linux-firmware-bnx2x`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314693), network unclaimed means it has no driver. You have to install proper driver for your ethernet NIC. Broadcom has a dirty history of Linux driver issue. Here is the [AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers#60395) post which specifically deals with all Broadcom driver issue.